# android preference back to default summary

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, preference, summary

I'm currently using a preference activity with fragments. I'm using android:summary in the xml file defining these preferences to set an explaining caption to the user and then setSummary on each preference when the user changes the preference value and everything works fine.
But when the user clears his/her choice in any EditTextPreference I would like to display back the explaining text from the xml tag android:summary. How could I achieve that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should set the default summray as a string resource in strings.xml and the You can set it back everytime You want.

Comment: Yes but my class is a generic one used for every EditTextPreference and I have a lot of them. I'm not going to add a specific entry in that class to get the corresponding string for each of them. I'd like a more generic way of doing this...
Something like setSummary(getDefaultSummary())... :)

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out.
Just add a resource string for every preference key called "key_summary" and use it as android:summary in the xml file defining the preferences.
Then in the onSharedPreferenceChanged function, just load the corresponding string as the summary as follows:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
{
    Preference preference = findPreference(key);
    if(preference instanceof EditTextPreference)
    {
        EditTextPreference editPref = (EditTextPreference)preference;
        String szPref = editPref.getText();
        if(null!=szPref&&0<szPref.length())
            editPref.setSummary(szPref);
        else
        {
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            int nSummary = getResources().getIdentifier(key + "_summary", "string", activity.getPackageName());
            if(0<nSummary)
                editPref.setSummary(getString(nSummary));
            else
                editPref.setSummary(szPref);
        }
    }
}
```